# What to do with application/octet files from Google Cloud storage?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I've extracted a large volume of Google Big Query data into Google Cloud storage. The files are transferred into a file format application/octet. I have no idea how to process this file type.

How can I convert this into something more familiar, ideally csv?

Comment: I'm guessing you are referring to the type of the file being marked as "application/octet-stream" in the GCS web browser. If you exported it as CSV from BigQuery, then it's just a normal CSV file(s). Read/download one and you'll see. Did you even try testing one of the files?!

Comment: @GrahamPolley - Ouch! Ha well I'll take it, I'm sure I'm more naive than you give me credit for though. I did try to test it, but didn't think to change the extension suffix, first to gzip then to csv after unpacking. Given your comment that's exactly what I've done now. 

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Just for posterity, as Graham mentioned "application/octet-stream" is not actually the file format just the HTTP content-type of the file. Depending on how you exported the file from BigQuery (using compression? which file format?) you should be able to just open it.

Comment: From memory just double clicking didn't seem to work, but changing the file format to .gzip or .csv did the trick fine. Then it responded as you'd expect.